# mypy and distributing a namespace package

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy, namespace-package

I have a set of namespace packages that are meant to run in a python3.6 environment.

They are each set up as follows:

```
if sys.version_info < (3, 6):
    print("Python versions < 3.6 unsupported", file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

setup(
    name="mynamespace.subpackage",
    version=VERSION,

    packages=[
        "mynamespace.subpackage",
    ],
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    package_data={
        "": [],
    },
    include_package_data=True,
    zip_safe=False,

    install_requires=[
        "mynamespace.core",  # May have explicit dependencies that are not cyclic
    ],

    namespace_packages=["mynamespace"],
    ...
)
```

All of the subpackages install just fine side-by-side.

The problem comes when I want to get robust type-checking via `mypy`.  `mypy` is unable to find the `mynamespace.core` subpackage when being run on the source files for `mynamespace.subpackage` (for example) which means that I don't get robust typing checking across my sub-package boundaries.

This appears to be a known problem:  https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/1645

Guido mentions that the workaround is to "add a dummy `__init__.py` or `__init__.pyi` files", but he doesn't really elaborate and it turns out that this isn't as obvious to me as I had hoped.  Adding those files to the *local* repo allows mypy to run over the local repo as expected, I can't figure out how to get access to the typing information in a sibling namespace package.

My question is: how would I modify `mynamespace.core` -- so that when installed, `mypy` is able to pick up it's type information in other modules?

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully you've fixed it by now (or given up!!) but for any fellow dwellers, the answer is to run:

`mypy --namespace-packages -p mynamespace.subpackage`

Note that when you use the `-p` arg you *cannot* specify a directory as well.